# Error after breaking long line of code in C

Tags: c

code:

```
for(int i = 0; *(str + i) != '\0'; i++){
    if(*(str + i) != 'a' ||
       *(str + i) != 'e' ||
       *(str + i) != 'i' ||
       *(str + i) != 'o' ||
       *(str + i) != 'u' ||
       *(str + i) != 'A' ||
       *(str + i) != 'E' ||
       *(str + i) != 'I' ||
       *(str + i) != 'O' ||
       *(str + i) != 'U' ||) {

        new_str[index] = *(str + i);
        index ++;
       }

    else{
      *(vowels + vow_index) = *(str + i);
      vow_index ++;

    }
  }
```

Error:

```
ex3.c:81:28: error: expected expression
       *(str + i) != 'U' ||) {
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

Why is this happening? I thought I could break long lines of code in C without worrying about indentation.

Comment: You can't have `||` at the end of the expression, it goes *between* conditions.

Comment: P.S. Please get out of the habit of using `*(str + i)`. `str[i]` is more idiomatic and understandable.

Comment: The `||` operator needs two operands. Also the condition of the `if` evaluates to `true` always (if it was correct syntactically).

Comment: For heaven's sake use `switch`, or better, `if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", str[i]) == NULL)) /* not a vowel */`

Comment: *"I thought I could break long lines of code in C without worrying about indentation."* Yes, you absolutely can do that. But that's not what you did. If you removed all of the line breaks, and put that `if` statement on a single line, you'd get exactly the same error from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `||` just before the last parenthesis. That will fix your compile error.
The logic of what you are trying to do, however, is not going to work. The condition is always going to evaluate to true. (Try changing `||` to `&&`)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trailing "||" at the end of your statement, after 'U'. Just remove it and it should be OK :)

About your code : you should rather store the vowels into a char array and compare your pointer to each increment of the array, this would improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is a logical OR operator, not a line break. You have a trailing operator in your last line, which should be `*(str + i) != 'U') {`